# Generating an array of primes and using it in the program

Tags: java, arrays, performance

I have generated first 10 million primes using the sieve of eratosthenes in Java. Following is the code for the same:

```
private static int[] gprime(int max) {
boolean[] isComposite = new boolean[max + 1];
for (int i = 2; i * i <= max; i++) {
    if (!isComposite [i]) {
        for (int j = i; i * j <= max; j++) {
            isComposite [i*j] = true;
        }
    }
}
int numPrimes = 0;
for (int i = 2; i <= max; i++) {
    if (!isComposite [i]) numPrimes++;
}
int [] primes = new int [numPrimes];
int index = 0;
for (int i = 2; i <= max; i++) {
    if (!isComposite [i]) primes [index++] = i;
}
return primes;
}
```

I need to use this array a lot of times in my program after generating this array of primes. If i keep writing

```
gprime(179424673)[i]
```

(179,424,673 is the ten millionth prime) whenever I need to access any item from the array, the execution is very inefficient as it would run the method over and over again.
How do I simply get an array to access any prime from that array?

P.S. Why do I have downvotes on this question? Are people who are new to programming simply downvoted and discouraged like this to ask any further questions on stackoverflow? I clearly mentioned what my question is along with the code of what I have done so far.

Comment: Store it in a variable?

Comment: `int[] result = gprime(179424673); int a = result[i];` ?

Comment: Thank you. Why do I have downvotes on this question?
Are people who are new to programming simply downvoted and discouraged like this to ask any further questions on stackoverflow?
I clearly mentioned what my question is along with the code of what I have done so far.

Comment: instead of array use ArrayList as easy to manipulate and iterate

Comment: @AmanArora: I didn't vote, so can only guess that it's because the error ("not realising you can store the array in a variable") is a fairly fundamental example of (not yet) understanding programming.  I don't mean this as a personal attack -- everyone has to start somewhere -- but if this wasn't just a temporary "blip" in your thinking, then you perhaps ought to consider looking for some basic grounding in programming.

Comment: @AmanArora In addition to what TripeHound said, I've gotten the feeling that SO prefers questions that are like "Here's my problem, *here's what I tried*, but now I'm stuck" more than "Here's my problem, how do I proceed?" It can be a subtle difference, but showing what you have tried and researched could go a long way towards a question receiving a positive response instead of a negative one.

Comment: I am blocked from asking questions because of this now. It just makes one feel sad and its demoralizing.
I simply asked what should I be doing for the program to be efficient as I could not figure out storing the array in a variable.

Comment: @AmanArora That's said, but SO is mainly meant as a site collection good questions and answers. Sure, there are thousands of people having similar problems to yours, but there's no chance of finding the answer as the problems are just arbitrary problems of the "what have I missed in a textbook" kind. Try Google, study more, maybe find a more forum oriented more towards helping than collecting. Also look at the other questions here.

Comment: I quit stackoverflow, anyways. It is seemingly full of arrogant people who just downvote the question because they feel like, "meh, thats a stupid fella with a stupid question".

Answer (score 0):

Store it as a class level constant,

```
public static final int[] PRIMES = gprime(179424673); // <-- use the biggest value
                                                      // you will need here.
```

Then you can access it (instead of `gprime(179424673)[i]`) with

```
PRIMES[i]
```